# Generate m3u8 playlist from *.ts files

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have generated hls videos using FFmpeg. But I forgot to put `-hls_list_size 0`. Now it contains only the last 4 files. Is there any way to generate only the .m3u8 playlist file using all *.ts files inside the folder?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not have the source or you do not want to re-construct the whole playlist, write a bash script to pick the duration of each segment using the command

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ts_files/sample_000.ts
```

Once you have the segment lengths, it should be quite simple IMHO.

Of-course, you'd want the bash to iterate through the `*.ts` files in a sorted order (by name/created at).

While the above may do the job, go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052883/create-m3u8-file-from-list-of-ts-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011563/generate-m3u8-on-the-fly-from-ts-files/52248797) once.